# XSLT to sum product of two attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath, sum

I have the following XML source structure:

```
<turnovers>
    <turnover repid="1" amount="500" rate="0.1"/>
    <turnover repid="5" amount="600" rate="0.5"/>
    <turnover repid="4" amount="400" rate="0.2"/>
    <turnover repid="1" amount="700" rate="0.05"/>
    <turnover repid="2" amount="100" rate="0.15"/>
    <turnover repid="1" amount="900" rate="0.25"/>
    <turnover repid="2" amount="1000" rate="0.18"/>
    <turnover repid="5" amount="200" rate="0.55"/>
    <turnover repid="9" amount="700" rate="0.40"/>
</turnovers>
```

I need an XSL:value-of select statement that will return the sum of the product of the rate attribute and the amount attribute for a given rep ID. So for rep 5 I need ((600 x 0.5) + (200 x 0.55)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="/turnovers">
    <val>
      <!-- call the sum function (with the relevant nodes) -->
      <xsl:call-template name="sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="turnover[@repid='5']" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </val>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sum">  
    <xsl:param name="nodes" />
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="curr" select="$nodes[1]" />

    <!-- if we have a node, calculate & recurse -->
    <xsl:if test="$curr">
      <xsl:variable name="runningsum" select="
        $sum + $curr/@amount * $curr/@rate
      " />
      <xsl:call-template name="sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
        <xsl:with-param name="sum"   select="$runningsum" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- if we don't have a node (last recursive step), return sum -->
    <xsl:if test="not($curr)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sum" />
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives:

```
<val>410</val>
```

The two `<xsl:if>`s can be replaced by a single `<xsl:choose>`. This would mean one less check during the recursion, but it also means two additional lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

In plain XSLT 1.0 you need a recursive template for this, for example:

```
  <xsl:template match="turnovers">
    <xsl:variable name="selectedId" select="5" />
    <xsl:call-template name="sum_turnover">
      <xsl:with-param name="turnovers" select="turnover[@repid=$selectedId]" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sum_turnover">
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="turnovers"  />
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="$turnovers[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="$turnovers[position()>1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="calc" select="$head/@amount * $head/@rate" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($tail)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$total + $calc" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum_turnover">
          <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total + $calc" />
          <xsl:with-param name="turnovers" select="$tail" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This solution is missing the "for a given @repid" part, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, you'll need to do some further work to select the distinct `repid`'s

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <xsl:variable name="totals">
            <product>
                <xsl:for-each select="turnovers/turnover">
                    <repid repid="{@repid}">
                        <value><xsl:value-of select="@amount * @rate"/></value>
                    </repid>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </product>
        </xsl:variable>
        <totals>
            <total repid="5" value="{sum($totals/product/repid[@repid='5']/value)}"/>   
        </totals>               
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I did not know you can create whole new nodes, assign it to a variable, and then query it. Neat, thanks John, will test it out.

Comment: @Ravish: You can't, until XSLT 2.0. In 1.0 you would need the node-set() extension function.

Answer (score 1):

**In XSLT 1.0 the use of [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) makes such problems easy to solve:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext"
 >
 <xsl:import href="zipWith.xsl"/>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vMultFun" select="document('')/*/f:mult-func[1]"/>    

    <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <xsl:call-template name="profitForId"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="profitForId">
      <xsl:param name="pId" select="1"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vrtfProducts">
          <xsl:call-template name="zipWith">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vMultFun"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pList1" select="/*/*[@repid = $pId]/@amount"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pList2" select="/*/*[@repid = $pId]/@rate"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfProducts)/*)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <f:mult-func/>
    <xsl:template match="f:mult-func" mode="f:FXSL">
     <xsl:param name="pArg1"/>
     <xsl:param name="pArg2"/>

     <xsl:value-of select="$pArg1 * $pArg2"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the originally posted source XML document, the correct result is produced:

**310**

**In XSLT 2.0 the same solution using [FXSL 2.0](http://fxsl.sf.net) can be expressed by an XPath one-liner:**

```
sum(f:zipWith(f:multiply(),
          /*/*[xs:decimal(@repid) eq 1]/@amount/xs:decimal(.),
          /*/*[xs:decimal(@repid) eq 1]/@rate/xs:decimal(.)
          )
     )
```

**The whole transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
>
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-zipWithDVC.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

 <!-- To be applied on testFunc-zipWith4.xml -->
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "sum(f:zipWith(f:multiply(),
              /*/*[xs:decimal(@repid) eq 1]/@amount/xs:decimal(.),
              /*/*[xs:decimal(@repid) eq 1]/@rate/xs:decimal(.)
              )
         )
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, this transformation produces the correct answer:

**310**

**Note the following**:

1. The [**`f:zipWith()`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-zipWithDVC.xsl?revision=1.2&view=markup) function takes as arguments a function `fun()` (of two arguments) and two lists of items having the same length. It produces a new list of the same length, whose items are the result of the pair-wise application of `fun()` on the corresponding `k`-th items of the two lists.
2. `f:zipWith()` as in the expression takes the function [**`f:multiply()`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-Operators.xsl?view=markup) and two sequences of corresponding "`ammount`" and "`rate`" attributes. The sesult is a sequence, each item of which is the product of the corresponding "`ammount`" and "`rate`".
3. Finally, the **[sum](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum)** of this sequence is produced.
4. There is no need to write an explicit recursion and it is also guaranteed that the behind-the scenes recursion used within `f:zipWith()` is never going to crash (for all practical cases) with "stack overflow"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
      version="2.0">

   <xsl:variable name="repid" select="5" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select=
         "sum(for $x in /turnovers/turnover[@repid=$repid] return $x/@amount * $x/@rate)"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can do this if you just need the value and not xml.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to do it in XSLT is probably to use programming language bindings, so that you can define your own XPath functions.