# Aggregate-function for sum and product in XPath

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Similar to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1333558/948404) I want to use XPath to calculate a sum over products in a structure like this:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <value>1.0</value>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>2.5</value>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </item>
    <!-- ... -->
</items>
```

Is there an XPath expression that calculates the sum of the products of each items `value` and `quantity`?

**Update:** The solution has to work with PHPs XSLTProcessor class meaning that it probably has to be XSLT 1.0 compliant. This is why I did not yet accept the two probably correct answers using XSLT 2.0. I could neither test them in my PHP implementation nor in my browser nor in the Tryit Editor [1] from w3schools. Sorry!

1. http://w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT to sum product of two attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333558/xslt-to-sum-product-of-two-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
sum(/items/item/(value * quantity))
```

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 transformation as verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="sum(/items/item/(value * quantity))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <value>1.0</value>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>2.5</value>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </item>
    <!-- ... -->
</items>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is output:**

```
8
```

**Explanation**:

In XPath 2.0 it is legal for a location step to be

`/(expression)`,

or even

`/someFunction(argumentList)`

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="item"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sumProducts">
   <xsl:param name="pNodes" select="/.."/>
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
      <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() >1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select=
      "$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/value * $pNodes[1]/quantity"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
8
```

**Do note**: Such kind of problems are easy to solve using the **[FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)**. The template to call is `transform-and-sum` .

Comment: Like I commented on the other answer this looks promising to me, but I can not get it to work with PHP. Is this a problem of PHP only supporting XSLT 1.0 / XPath 1.0, or did I not adapt it correctly? Is there a similar solution for version 1.0?

Comment: @hielsnoppe: AFAIK PHP uses libxml/libxslt, which only implements XPath 1.0 / XSLT 1.0. It is impossible to calculate the wanted value with a single XPath 1.0 expression only. If you are interested in an XSLT 1.0 solution, please, confirm, and I'll provide such.

Comment: Thank you for clarification on this! I now came up with a solution myself, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="sum(/items/item/(value * quantity))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks promising to me, but can't get it to work with PHPs XSLTProcessor. Is this a problem of PHP or didn't I adapt it correctly?

Comment: trouble with writing things from memory

Answer (score 1):

Based on this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/1334165/948404 I came up with a solution compliant with XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0, which are implemented by libxml/libxslt, used by PHPs implementation of `XSLTProcessor` (thanks to @Dimitre Novatchev for confirmation).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/items">
        <xsl:call-template name="recursivesum">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="*" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recursivesum">
        <xsl:param name="items" />
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />
        <xsl:variable name="head" select="$items[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="tail" select="$items[position()>1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="thissum" select="$head/value * $head/quantity" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($tail)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$sum+$thissum" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="recursivesum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum+$thissum" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$tail" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```