# XSLT 2.0 - Sum Element Names that Increment

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm working on generating a sum of element names that when they exist increment up.

XML Example:

```
<Distributions>
<DIST_DISTRIBUTIONMETHOD_1>Check to Other</DIST_DISTRIBUTIONMETHOD_1>
<DIST_CREDITOR_1>MOTORS FINANCE</DIST_CREDITOR_1>
<DIST_AMOUNT_1>16710.04</DIST_AMOUNT_1>
<DIST_NET_1>No</DIST_NET_1>
<DIST_DISTRIBUTIONMETHOD_2>Check to Other</DIST_DISTRIBUTIONMETHOD_2>
<DIST_CREDITOR_2>WILLIAM HOOK</DIST_CREDITOR_2>
<DIST_AMOUNT_2>1239.86</DIST_AMOUNT_2>
<DIST_NET_2>Yes</DIST_NET_2>
</Distributions>
```

I need to Sum DIST_AMOUNT_1, 2, etc, up to a possible 15 in total that may or may not exist.

Thusfar, I've assigned each DIST_AMOUNT to a variable after checking to see if it exists.  The sum itself is where I'm having issues as there is nothing populating for the sum and I've no idea why, I've beaten my head on this and googled for answers for days now.  Any help is appreciated.

My XSL code thusfar:

```
<xsl:variable name="DIST_TMP_1">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//DIST_AMOUNT_1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(//DIST_AMOUNT_1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(0.00)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="DIST_TMP_2">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//DIST_AMOUNT_2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(//DIST_AMOUNT_2)"/>
                </xsl:when>                 
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(0.00)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="DIST_TMP_3">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//DIST_AMOUNT_3">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(//DIST_AMOUNT_3)"/>
                </xsl:when>                 
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(0.00)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="ECD070_TOTAL_VAR">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($DIST_TMP_1+$DIST_TMP_2+DIST_TMP_3)"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate-function for sum and product in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669313/aggregate-function-for-sum-and-product-in-xpath). There's an XSLT 1.0 part to the top answer; you can leave out the 'product' part, since you only need sum.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate as the example only uses 'value'.  Not value_1, value_2, etc.  These elements are not the same name so that code doesn't work for this problem.

Comment: All you need to do is change the expression to match the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you simply do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Distributions/*[starts-with(name(), 'DIST_AMOUNT_')])" />
```

---

Or, if you must be explicit, do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum((DIST_AMOUNT_1, DIST_AMOUNT_2, DIST_AMOUNT_3, ... DIST_AMOUNT_15))" />
```

(this is from the context of `Distributions`). There is no need to test each one of these for existence: non-existing nodes will simply be ignored.

Comment: Using the first option it is providing '0' as the sum, when it should be 17949.90.  It is at least giving some output now, so thank you for that!

Comment: The explicit option gives a syntax error, it hasn't liked the commas when I've used them previously, its why I was using plus signs.

Comment: @DanaWilliams Both suggestion were tested using an XSLT 2.0 processor (the first one should actually work in XSLT 1.0, too). Which processor are you using? --- P.S. Using plus signs inside sum() is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Aha, Distrubtions needed to be capitalized, you so rock for the solution Michael!  I have beaten myself brainless for days working on this and you have it in one line!  :)

Comment: Oh yes, XML is case-sensitive. This has tripped many unsuspecting souls.